# Get time of NTP-Server from Android App

Tags: java, android, networking, client, ntp

Dear android developers,

I'm trying to implement the sntpclient class in my application but it didn't work.

Class: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java

in my code I have the following lines:

```
public void onClickBtn(View v)
{
    SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
     if (client.requestTime("pool.ntp.org", 10)) {
         long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference();
         Toast.makeText(this, "Offset: " + now, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

I really don't know what the meaning of network timeout is in this case.

It would be great, when someone has any idea or tip for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the issue?What happens?

Comment: nothing happens.I dont know what I should type for "network timeout" currently it is "10"...

Comment: I dont think that can be the issue.Did you debugged the app & checked if its going inside `if` block?

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing, give me some minutes please...

Comment: its trying the if block but after that nothing happens, it seems, that  the requirement didn't fill... the url is wrong or the "network timeout" maybe something is missing in the android manifest?
I've implemented internet and network status

Comment: Check if you have given `Internet` permission, also check if you can access internet on device's browser also try increasing time out of the request

Comment: incresed time to 6000 and he will get out from the code in this line of the sntp class:
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

Comment: these are my permissions:     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Permissions looks good..Internet on device?

Comment: yes, all the time. I've tried wifi and 3g.

Comment: Try changing host to `http://pool.ntp.org`

Comment: didn't worked as well...

Comment: can you try with other hosts instead of `pool.ntp.org`?

Comment: I did it with some others, none of them worked... for example 1.de.ntp.org . I can ping all of these servers, but in the code he didn't want to use them...

Answer (score 4):

You should put it in AsyncTask like this :

```
class GetNTPAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            private SntpClient sntpClient = new SntpClient();
            return sntpClient.requestTime("pool.ntp.org", 30000);
        }
}
```

Timeout: network timeout in milliseconds. So i use 30000 mean 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this Full sample:

```
class getCurrentNetworkTime extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        timeClient.setDefaultTimeout(3000);
        InetAddress inetAddress = null;
        boolean is_locale_date = false;
        try {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(G.TIME_SERVER);
            TimeInfo timeInfo = null;
            timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
            long localTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
            long serverTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
            if (new Date(localTime) != new Date(serverTime))
                is_locale_date = true;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("UnknownHostException: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IOException: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return is_locale_date;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(boolean local_date) {
        if(!local_date) {
            Log.e("Check ", "dates not equal" + local_date);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
new getCurrentNetworkTime().execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your manifest has this one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```